# SortBy em JSF, breve explicação do que ele faz?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Alguém poderia dar uma explicação qual a função do `sortBy` no `JSF`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você quer dizer o `sortBy` do Primefaces, não é?

SortBy é a expressão usada para ordenar uma lista (DataTable)

[DataTable - Sort](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/sort.xhtml)